# Ansible, with_subelements and skip_missing does not work

Tags: ansible

I have the following problem:
A host_var defining my nginx sites (excerpt):

```
nginx_sites:
- server:
    name: site1
    location1:
      config:
        name: "/"
        [...]
- server:
    name: site2
    location1:
      config:
        name: "/"
        [...]
    location2:
      config:
        name: "/secretspace"
        [...]
      htaccess:
        username:
          password: somepassword
```

In this example I have 2 sites. The second one has two locations where the second one has a subelement named "htaccess". This is what I want to use in order to create an corresponding htaccess file.

I tried this ansible task:

```
- name: Creating htaccess files if nessecary
  debug: msg="Huhu {{ item.0.name }}  {{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
  - "{{ nginx_sites }}"
  - "htaccess"
  - flags:
    skip_missing: True
```

This **should** imho print a debug statement, when there is a subelement named "htaccess" element in `nginx_sites` or skip if it is not there.
But nothing happens:

```
TASK [nginx : Creating htaccess files if nessecary]  ****************************
task path: /home/dakky/devzone/ansible-cfg-mgmt/roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml:65

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
hostname       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with_subelements` is used to iterate over **list** subelements.
If you modify your input data to make a list of locations instead of named properties (location1, location2, etc):

```
nginx_sites:
  - server:
      name: site1
      locations:
        - config:
            name: "/"
  - server:
      name: site2
      locations:
        - config:
            name: "/"
        - config:
            name: "/secretspace"
          htaccess:
            username:
              password: somepassword
```

Then you can iterate your locations and select those with htaccess defined:

```
- name: Creating htaccess files if nessecary
  debug: msg="Huhu {{ item.0.server.name }}  {{ item.1.htaccess }}"
  when: item.1.htaccess is defined
  with_subelements:
  - "{{ nginx_sites }}"
  - "server.locations"
```

Also note that you should specify "full path" for subelements. In your original example `htaccess` will never match anything, but `server.location2.htaccess` will (although rising error that this item is not a list).

Answer (score 5):

This works for me

```
- name: Creating htaccess files if nessecary
  debug: msg="Huhu {{ item.0.name }}  {{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
  - "{{ nginx_sites }}"
  - "htaccess"
  - skip_missing: True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I was looking for this. I have a question is there any book with all the syntax?