# Ansible with_subelements (Lists)

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to set up Apache virtual hosts along with databases, but not all Vhosts will have databases (1 or more).

I've tried quite a lot and also tried to adapt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355598/ansible-with-subelements-and-skip-missing-does-not-work), but nothing really worked. I did a lot of try&error for quite some hours and came up with this:

My `host_vars` (excerpt):

```
web_vhosts:
  - vhost:
      name: domain1.tld
      enabled: true
      serveradmin_email: info@example.org
      https: true
      redirect_to_https: true
      dns_a_record: 1.2.3.4
      update_dns: false
  - vhost:
      name: domain2.tld
      enabled: true
      serveradmin_email: info@example.org
      https: true
      redirect_to_https: true
      dns_a_record: 1.2.3.4
      update_dns: false
      mysql:
        - name: wordpress1
          user: myuser
          password: secret
```

This is how far I am:

```
- name: Ensure databases
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ item.1.name }}"
    state: present
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  when: item.0.mysql is defined
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ web_vhosts }}"
    - "mysql"
```

Which errors in:

```
fatal: [examplehost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "could not find 'mysql' key in iterated item '{'vhost': {'name': 'domain1.tld', 'enabled': True, 'serveradmin_email': 'info@example.org', 'https': True, 'redirect_to_https': True, 'dns_a_record': '1.2.3.4', 'update_dns': False}}'"}
```

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `web_vhosts` is a list composed of dictionaries where the first element is `vhost`. You need to find the subelement `vhost.mysql` instead of `mysql`. This should fix your issue:

```
- name: Ensure databases
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ item.1.name }}"
    state: present
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  loop: "{{ web_vhosts | subelements('vhost.mysql', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

Comment: Wow perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no *mysql* key in the first item of the list *web_vhosts*

> {"msg": "could not find 'mysql' key in iterated item '{'vhost': {'name': domain1.tld' ...

Set [{'skip_missing': True}](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html). For example

```
- name: Ensure databases
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ item.1.name }}"
    state: present
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', web_vhosts, 'mysql', {'skip_missing': True}) }}"
```

---

It might be a good idea to test the loop first

```
- name: Debug
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', web_vhosts, 'mysql', {'skip_missing': True}) }}"
```

---

Alternatively, it's possible to use *subelements* as a [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#subelements-filter)

```
  loop: "{{ web_vhosts | subelements('mysql', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Now I don't get an error but also no database is created. I think nothing matched:

    TASK [web : Ensure databases] ***********

Comment: You're welcome. Try and test it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The debug doesn't produce output:

TASK [web : Debug] ****************... (empty line)